# Optimal way to count total of list comprehension result in django

Tags: django, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension in my view I use since I have to filter based on model calculated fields.

```
leaseterms = LeaseTerm.objects.filter( is_active = True )
tobe_payed_terms = [obj for obj in leaseterms if obj.current_balance < 0]
```

I use it to display all the fields in my report.

Currently I have to add a dashboard where I just want to display count of total units of this list comprehension.

What is most performance wise optimal way of doing so?

(I might have few cases like this in my dashboard)

### MODEL - I use SQLlite on DEV and POSTGRES on PROD and TEST

```
    class LeaseTerm(CommonInfo):
        version = IntegerVersionField( )
        start_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='start_period',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        end_period = models.ForeignKey(Period, related_name='end_period',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        lease = models.ForeignKey(Lease,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        increase  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
        amount  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
        is_renewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_renewal_letter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        renewal_letter_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


        _current_period  = None
        _total_current = None
        _total_payment = None
        _total_current_payment = None
        _total_discount = None
        _total_current_discount = None
        _current_tobe_payed = None
        _current_balance = None
        _is_current_term = None
        _tenant = None




        def _get_total(self):
            from payment.models import LeasePayment
            from conditions.models import LeaseDiscount



            total_payment_dict = LeasePayment.objects.filter(leaseterm_id=self.id, is_active = True ).aggregate(Sum('amount'))



            if total_payment_dict ['amount__sum']:
                total_payment =  total_payment_dict['amount__sum'] 
            else:  
                total_payment =  0

            total_discount_dict = LeaseDiscount.objects.filter(leaseterm_id=self.id, is_active = True ).aggregate(Sum('amount'))


            if total_discount_dict ['amount__sum']:
                total_discount =  total_discount_dict['amount__sum'] 
            else:  
                total_discount =  0



            current_date=datetime.datetime.now().date()
            current_period_dict = Period.objects.filter(start_date__lte=current_date,end_date__gte=current_date, is_active = True ).aggregate(Max('order_value'))


            if current_period_dict['order_value__max']:
                current_period =  current_period_dict['order_value__max'] 
            else:  
                current_period =  0

            tenant = LeaseTenant.objects.filter(lease=self.lease, is_financially_accountable=True ).last()


            if  (self.start_period.order_value <= current_period  <= self.end_period.order_value) and (self.is_active == True):

                is_current_term_dict =  True

            else:  
                is_current_term_dict =  False
                current_period = self.end_period.order_value


            current_discount_dict = LeaseDiscount.objects.filter(leaseterm_id=self.id, 
                is_active = True, period_date__gte=self.start_period,
                 period_date__lte=current_period).aggregate(Sum('amount'))

            if current_discount_dict ['amount__sum']:
                current_discount =  current_discount_dict['amount__sum'] 
            else:  
                current_discount =  0



            current_periods_number = current_period - self.start_period.order_value + 1

            current_tobe_payed =  current_periods_number * self.amount -  current_discount

            current_balance =  total_payment - current_tobe_payed





            self._current_period = current_period
            self._total_payment = total_payment
            self._total_discount = total_discount
            self._current_tobe_payed  = current_tobe_payed 
            self._current_balance = current_balance
            self._is_current_term = is_current_term_dict

            if tenant is not None:
                self._tenant = tenant.tenant
            else:
                self._tenant = None


        @property
        def is_current_term(self):
            if self._is_current_term is None:
                self._get_total()
            return self._is_current_term 

        @property
        def tenant(self):
            if self._tenant is None:
                self._get_total()
            return self._tenant    

        @property
        def current_tobe_payed(self):
            if self._current_tobe_payed is None:
                self._get_total()
            return self._current_tobe_payed


        @property
        def current_balance(self):
            if self._current_balance is None:
                self._get_total()
            return self._current_balance

        @property
        def current_period(self):
            if self._current_period is None:
                self._get_total()
            return self._current_period   

        @property
        def total_payment(self):
            if self._total_payment is None:
                self._get_total()
            return self._total_payment

        @property
        def total_discount(self):
            if self._total_discount is None:
                self._get_total()
            return self._total_discount


        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.full_clean()
            return super(LeaseTerm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u' %i %s %s ' % (self.id, self.start_period, self.end_period)




    @with_author
    class Period(CommonInfo):
        version = IntegerVersionField( )
        order_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        start_date = models.DateField()
        end_date = models.DateField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        is_special = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_marked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        _is_current = models.NullBooleanField( blank=True, null=True, default=None)
        #not_terminated_active_objects = NotTerminatedActiveManager() 
        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s %i %s ' % ("#", self.order_value, self.name)



class Lease(CommonInfo):
    version = IntegerVersionField( )

    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False)



    _total = None
    _total_current = None

    _total_payment = None
    _total_current_payment = None

    _total_discount = None
    _total_current_discount = None



    def _get_total(self):
        from payment.models import LeasePayment
        from conditions.models import LeaseDiscount



        total_payment_dict = LeasePayment.objects.filter(lease_id=self.id, is_active = True ).aggregate(Sum('amount'))


        if total_payment_dict ['amount__sum']:
            total_payment =  total_payment_dict['amount__sum'] 
        else:  
            total_payment =  0

        total_discount_dict = LeaseDiscount.objects.filter(leaseterm__lease_id=self.id, is_active = True ).aggregate(Sum('amount'))

        if total_discount_dict ['amount__sum']:
            total_discount =  total_discount_dict['amount__sum'] 
        else:  
            total_discount =  0







        self._total_payment = total_payment
        self._total_discount = total_discount
        self._total = total_payment + total_discount



    @property
    def total_payment(self):
        if self._total_payment is None:
            self._get_total()
        return self._total_payment

    @property
    def total_discount(self):
        if self._total_discount is None:
            self._get_total()
        return self._total_discount

    @property
    def total(self):
        if self._total is None:
            self._get_total()
        return self._total


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %i %s ' % ("lease#", self.id, self.unit)

    def clean(self):
        model = self.__class__
        if self.unit and (self.is_active == True)  and model.objects.filter(unit=self.unit, is_terminated = False , is_active = True).exclude(id=self.id).count() > 0:
            raise ValidationError('Unit has active lease already, Terminate existing one prior to creation of new one or create a not active lease '.format(self.unit))




    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(Lease, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField("creation date", auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField("modification date", auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: I remember asking a question from you about generated fields a while ago. I guess this is related. Can you post your model. Also can you let us know what your database server is?

Comment: @e4c5 Updated my post

Comment: This can be achieved with carefull use of Case/When and F however you would need to post all relevent models and also without the '>'

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far:

leaseterms = LeaseTerm.objects.filter( is_active = True )
    negative_balance_term = [obj.id for obj in leaseterms if obj.current_balance < 0]
    count_negative_balance_term = LeaseTerm.objects.filter(id__in=negative_balance_term).count()